# Getting caught in an infinite loop with this program that is supposed to output the smallest possible integer

Tags: c++

hope someone could help me this and where the error in my code is.  I have to write a program for class that does not use arrays or vectors and am restricted in using only nested loops for the exercise.  The program is supposed to run through a series of loops and then outputs the lowest possible integer solution to the problem (a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3). I'm still learning c++ so please forgive any ignorance or sloppy coding. Also thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio> 


using namespace std; 

int a, b, c, d, n, a_pow, b_pow, c_pow, d_pow, exp_pow, smaller_int,   larger_int, my_num; 


int main()
{


while (n == exp_pow && n == my_num)
{
    for (a = 1; a < 20; a++)
    {
        a_pow = pow(a, 3);
        larger_int = (a_pow + b_pow);

        for (b = 1; b < 20; b++)
        {
            b_pow = pow(b, 3);
            smaller_int = (a_pow + b_pow);
            if (larger_int < smaller_int)
            {
                smaller_int = larger_int;
            } 
                for (c = 1; c < 20; c++)
                {
                    c_pow = pow(c, 3); 
                    larger_int = (c_pow + d_pow);
                    if (larger_int < smaller_int)
                    {
                        smaller_int = larger_int;
                    }
                        for (d = 1; d < 20; d++)
                        {
                            d_pow = pow(d, 3); 
                            larger_int = (c_pow + d_pow);
                            if (larger_int < smaller_int)
                            {
                                smaller_int = larger_int;
                                exp_pow = smaller_int; 
                            }
                        }

                }

        }
    }

}

cout << smaller_int << endl;    
return 0;
}
```

Edit: 
I think I pretty much got it to work, not sure if the computation is right, but was able to produce an output from the code. Thank you to the ones that did provide some insight. Yes I was not updating the variables correctly while inside the loop. Now I just have to check my logic.

On a side note, down voted for asking a question??? Smh.

Comment: You never change `n` or `exp_pow` inside the `while`. So if your code ever go inside the while, it will loop forever. BTW, `for (a = 1; a < 20; a++) larger_sum = n; {}` is different than `for (a = 1; a < 20; a++){ larger_sum = n; }`

Comment: Have you debugged this and determined which loop can't escape?

Comment: The smallest possible integer is either `0` or `1` or `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, depending on what you actually mean.

Comment: C++ is not a declarative language. Saying e.g. `a_pow = pow(a, 3);` does not establish a general relationship between `a_pow` and `a`. It is a simple assignment of a computed value, and `a_pow` is completely unaffected by what happens later to `a`, if anything.

Comment: There is also `larger_sum = n;` before `{`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies. @Joseph Duty, I currently do not use a debugger, just Sublime and a terminal.

Comment: @Chris_Frost Use a debugger then. Such kind of questions is off-topic here.

Comment: @Wendelsilva, I think the professor is trying to stress variable manipulation within loop statements and I kinda figured that the issue is in the loop something is not updating, I'm just not sure where that line of code should go. I tried overriding those variables on the last in the last if statement, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get technical, the while loop is what never ends.

It's because you never assign a value to a, b, c, or d before you do:

```
a_pow = pow(a, 3); 
b_pow = pow(b, 3); 
c_pow = pow(c, 3);
d_pow = pow(d, 3);
```

So a,b,c,d are all 0, and thus a_pow:d_pow are all also 0. So when you do this:

```
n = (a_pow + b_pow);   
exp_pow = (c_pow + d_pow)
```

(and by the way you need a semi-colon at the end of the 2nd line there), both n and exp_pow = 0.

Since your loop never reassigns values to either n or ex_pow, this:

```
while (n == exp_pow)
```

is always true. I should add that there are a lot of other problems in the code, as well. But this does answer your actual question.